# How to distinguish introns, exons, and UTR from hg19 file

Tags: bioinformatics

I have an HG19 file in FastQ format, and I want to know the location range of all introns, exons, and UTR on each chromosome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UCSC genome browser to get a .bed file with coordinates of many different features in the genome. I pre-made a query for you for known canonical gene regions at this link, but you can play around with the options to define any areas of interest.

https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=845990667_YQp3YrxGqKGT8rU8wII1lRTGIKob&clade=mammal&org=Human&db=hg19&hgta_group=genes&hgta_track=knownGene&hgta_table=knownCanonical&hgta_regionType=range&position=chr8%3A128%2C750%2C440-128%2C750%2C640&hgta_outputType=primaryTable&hgta_outFileName=

You can then use `bedtools intersect -a file1 -b file2` to intersect the coordinates in your .fastq file with the coordinates in the .bed file. Here is another handy link that shows you how to do that https://www.biostars.org/p/210574/ and the documentation for `bedtools intersect` command https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html